# In react js when I Import a makeRequest

Tags: reactjs

[In react js when I import makeRequest then I got a error below the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zElga.png)

Comment: It seems to be clearly stating that variables REACT_APP_ISUSER & REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID are not defined

Comment: yes its define in env file